# Download Json as file: IE-11 throwing 414 Request-URI Too Large

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to download json object as cvs file. This JSON object is actually made out of a Java object that is in the browser itself. I am not firing any network request to get.
It is working fine in Chrome but IE-11 throws below error in Network->Response tab.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> 
<html><head> 
<title>414 Request-URI Too Large</title> 
</head><body> 
<h1>Request-URI Too Large</h1> 
<p>The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity 
limit for this server.<br /> 
</p> 
<hr> 
<address>Omniture DC/2.0.0 Server at *.112.2O7.net Port 80</address> 
</body></html>
```

In the console , I am getting this.

```
The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
```

My code in javascripts is as below:

```
  var fileName = "Group Assignment";
        var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);
        var link = document.getElementById('download-as-csv');   
        link.href = uri;
        link.download = fileName + ".csv";
        link.innerHTML = 'Download as CSV';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can do that in this way. Microsoft Internet Explorer has a [limit up to 2048 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string) for URIs.

Instead it should be better you serve this CSV from a diferent page and point IE to get from there or use `msSaveOrOpenBlob` example:

```
navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(new Blob(CSV.split('')), { type: 'text/csv' }), fileName + ".csv");
```

*works only from IE 10 and above

Comment: Ok, then how do I do that?

Comment: Excellent, So I write this on click event of download-as-csv element? Excuse my naiiveness

Comment: Just put this:  `if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob)link.onclick = function(ev){navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(new Blob([new Uint8Array(CSV.split(''))], { type: 'text/csv' }), fileName + ".csv"); ev.preventDefault(); return false;}` below `var link = document.getElementById('download-as-csv'); `

Comment: Now I can download the file. Thanks.But the problem , it's in binary not plain text.

Comment: trying change type from "text/csv" to "text/csv;charset=utf-8"